# Передача параметра в поток

Tags: c++, многопоточность, классы

Есть класс. В поток есть возможность передать параметр. В примере ниже я туда передал строку и вывел ее в консоль. Но вот беда.. Мой экземпляр класса для потока не существует. То есть, я, конечно, могу создать еще один экземпляр класса в потоке и работать с ним, но хотелось бы как-то в поток передать тот экземпляр, с которым я работаю в `main()`. Необходимо иметь доступ к объектам класса и изменять их при определенных условиях. Например, из потока изменить значение `bool checked` и выполнить метод `method1()`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass(int value) {
        this->value = value;
        checked = false;
    }
    ~SomeClass() {
        cout << "The end" << endl;
    }
    void method1() {
        cout << value;
        checked = true;
    }
private:
    int value;
    bool checked;
};


DWORD WINAPI MyThread(LPVOID param) {
    cout << ((string*)param)[0] << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    SomeClass SC(5);
    SC.method1();

    DWORD thID;
    HANDLE handle;
    string str = "hello";
    handle = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, MyThread, &str, NULL, &thID);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Есть предположение, что вот так:
(работает, но с тем же самым экземпляром я работаю?)

```
handle = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, MyThread, &SC, NULL, &thID);
```

и

```
DWORD WINAPI MyThread(LPVOID param) {
    SomeClass SC2 = ((SomeClass*)param)[0];
    SC2.method1();
    //cout << ((string*)param)[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что Вам мешает передать в поток как параметр указатель на созданный в main() экземпляр класса?

Comment: @dr. F.I.N. как именно ? Знаний, извините, не хватает

Comment: А вот если небыло бы потока что бы вы делали? В случае если за пределами `main` вызвана ф-ция  `MyThread`? Вот тоже самое и тут.

Comment: @nick_n_a вместо потока была бы функция, но и туда я не знаю как передать экземпляр класса..

Comment: Поглядите в документацию к `CreateThread`. После того, как разберетесь с передачей, возьмитесь за синхронизацию.

Comment: @VTT, спасибо. Синхронизацию чего с чем ?

Comment: Синхронизацию доступа к объектам класса из разных потоков. Синхронизацию самих потоков. Вообще к чему этот вопрос не очень понятно. В коде же уже передается в поток указатель на объект строку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, это можно сделать так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass(int value): m_value(value)
    {  }

    SomeClass(const SomeClass&) =  delete;

    int add(int v){
        m_mutex.lock(); // Тут лучше использовать lock_guard, но не буду усложнять
        int tmp = m_value;
        m_value += v;
        m_mutex.unlock();
        return tmp;
    }

    ~SomeClass() {
        std::cout << "~SomeClass" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int m_value;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass foo(10);

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
        threads.emplace_back([&foo, i]{
            int addedValue = 1 << i;
            int oldValue = foo.add(addedValue);
            std::cout << "Поток " << i << " прибавил " << addedValue << " к " << oldValue << std::endl;
        });
    }

    for(auto& thread: threads){
       thread.join(); // Обязательно нужно дождатья завершения потоков
    }
    return 0;
}
```

У вас была правильная идея, но в строке `SomeClass SC2 = ((SomeClass*)param)[0];` нет массива, нужно просто преобразовать `void*` в `SomeClass*` :

`SomeClass* SC2 = reinterpret_cast<SomeClass*>(param);`

Ну и о синхронизации нужно позаботиться, в моём примере это мьютекс, в winapi это критические секции.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Только начинаю освоение потоков и winapi. Буду разбираться что и как в Вашем примере

Comment: @Григорий , описание используемых мной структур можете найти [тут](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) или в английской версии. Если хотите изучить стандартную библиотеку потоков, рекомендую почитать `Энтони Уильямс: Параллельное программирование на С++ в действии. Практика разработки многопоточных программ`.